# How to determine salesforce config or format

Tags: php, api, configuration, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

salesforce provide two types of format,

```
Person account 
and Business Account,
```

Is there any way we can determine if the Salesforce supports Person Accounts or standard Business Accounts.

using salesforce API and php integration.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Person Accounts are enabled in an Org you will see additional fields on the Account object. Perhaps the most telling is the [`isPersonAccount`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_account.htm#i1438064) field. If this is present then Person Accounts are enabled.

You could also check for a RecordType where IsPersonType = true. See [Person Account Record Types](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_guidelines_personaccounts.htm)

```
SELECT Name, SobjectType,IsPersonType 
FROM RecordType 
WHERE SobjectType='Account' AND IsPersonType=True
```

Incidentally, the http://salesforce.stackexchange.com site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.